# Split Single polygon into mulitple polygon geopandas

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, geopandas, shapefile

I have a shapefile I'm converting to a wkt to join with some other data. Unfortunately, some of the polygon field values are too long for excels's string limit (30,000). How do I split a polygon column if the string length is more than a certain value.

I've used the geopandas method explode(), but it doesn't resolve all the cases.

```
import geopandas
myshpfile = geopandas.read_file("cb_2018_us_county_500k/cb_2018_us_county_500k.shp") 
gd = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(myshpfile)
exploded = gd.explode(index_parts=True)
exploded.to_file('test_county_exploded.csv', driver='CSV', geometry= 'AS_WKT')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at Apache Parquet rather than CSV format. It has far less limitations and also lead to much lighter files.
Geopandas fully supports it via the functions: `geopandas.read_parquet` ([documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_parquet.html#geopandas-read-parquet)) and `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_parquet` ([documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_parquet.html))

You will need to install `pyarrow` ([pypi reference](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/)) to test this solution.